# Postgres: How to run WHERE statement in BYTEA[]?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to find all rows where `legacy_message.account_keys` of type `BYTEA[]` contains a given value.

This returns no rows. What went wrong?

```sql
SELECT *  
FROM transaction 
WHERE (legacy_message).account_keys && ARRAY[decode('2616138d49327dbfe7e10498e6237d56195bff4a1d9293b03e5c875fd83a2c8b','hex')];
```

The value to lookup `decode('2616138d49327dbfe7e10498e6237d56195bff4a1d9293b03e5c875fd83a2c8b','hex')` was obtained from DBeaver. This value is prominently recurs in these rows.

DBeaver screenshot:
[image]

## Edit- schema

The complete schema is on [github](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-accountsdb-plugin-postgres/blob/master/scripts/create_schema.sql)

```sql
CREATE TYPE "TransactionMessage" AS (
    header "TransactionMessageHeader",
    account_keys BYTEA[],
    recent_blockhash BYTEA,
    instructions "CompiledInstruction"[]
);

CREATE TABLE transaction (
    slot BIGINT NOT NULL,
    signature BYTEA NOT NULL,
    is_vote BOOL NOT NULL,
    message_type SMALLINT, -- 0: legacy, 1: v0 message
    legacy_message "TransactionMessage",
    v0_loaded_message "LoadedMessageV0",
    signatures BYTEA[],
    message_hash BYTEA,
    meta "TransactionStatusMeta",
    write_version BIGINT,
    updated_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    index BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT transaction_pk PRIMARY KEY (slot, signature)
);
```

`account_keys` for the required row contains the below value in base64 format. How do I extract this row by passing `x2616138d49327dbfe7e10498e6237d56195bff4a1d9293b03e5c875fd83a2c8`?

```
{xb02396cc11523621dc787d9b984639fbfae16158195e19418e6b2ef56b0db49,x2616138d49327dbfe7e10498e6237d56195bff4a1d9293b03e5c875fd83a2c8}
```

Comment: Where should legacy_message come from? And `didn't work` is a rather useless comment, it doesn't say anything about what is happing. No error message, no example, just nothing. And my favorite SQL editor doesn't like images as input, can't do anything with it. Please use plain text.

Comment: You could've [`WHERE decode(...)=ANY((legacy_message).account_keys)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-ANY-SOME) but the single-element array overlap with `&&` is perfectly fine as well: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/HIZYZShI). I'm guessing what Frank's guessing, that your problem lies elsewhere. Maybe you didn't show some other condition that's causing a mismatch? Maybe you're doing something to the text representation of the bytea before decoding? Please share the DDL and some more context, especially what `legacy_message` is exactly

Comment: @FrankHeikens check updated question. I provided the schema and data